# resume using php variable in other php file without including or requiring previous file

Tags: php

So I have a complicated PHP file that does some calculations and data-manipulation for me, what it does it not important, anyway I want to be able to access some of the variables I used in that file from a different PHP file.

I know I could include or require the first php file in the second php file, but then when one loads the second php file, one would be loading and re-preforming all the tasks in the first php file.

I want to run the first php file and then run the second file and have the second file pick up from where the first file left off in terms of the values of variables I used.

How can I do this?

I would prefer not to store the values of the variables I am going to use in a database adn the recover them in the second file, but if using a database is the only solution then please let me know.

Comment: It would be nice to see some code as opposed to just ideas.

Comment: If it's per user within a session, use $_SESSION, that's what it's there for ?

Comment: You can take a look at 'shared memory'. But actually it is difficult to give any hints with only so little details you give... For example: are you talking about cli php usage? Or are these web requests?

Comment: @karancan the code behind the calculations is proprietary and I can't share that. It is also really long. The other code is just printing the variables. so `echo $data1;`

Comment: Sessions could be an alternative to “transfer” values between different scripts.

Comment: @adeneo It is per user, but there is no logging in happening. Should I still take a look at sessions?

Comment: @arkascha don't know what cli php usage is. There aren't web requests. It is computations that the first php file makes and then the results are stored in variables. But I can't edit the first file so I need to have a second file that can print those variables.

Comment: You don't need a user to be logged in, any user specific data can be stored in the $_SESSION global.

Comment: @adeneo Then sessions is what I think I'm looking for. I have never used them. Can you post an answer with tips on how to use them and maybe a good reference?

Comment: CLI means `command line interface`, so some process you start by issuing a command in a command interpreter ("shell"). So if this is not CLI _and_ not web requests... then how are those scripts started? By a cron action?

Comment: @arkascha Oh, no. They are started by web requests. My bad. I misunderstood.

Comment: OK, then that is plain usage: the easiest is using sessions as mentioned millions of times here. Alternatives exist, but they are more complex. So unless you have more and very special requirements - don't bother.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the $_SESSION superglobal to store user data across a site / application for each user.

In the first file you'd do something like :

```
<?php

    // do shitload of calculations here !

    if(empty( session_id() )) session_start(); //check if there is a session
                                               //and start one if there is'nt

    $_SESSION['myData'] = "results from my calculations goes here";

?>
```

In the next file that data is now available :

```
<?php

    $data = isset( $_SESSION['myData'] ) ? $_SESSION['myData'] : 'Not available';

    echo "Result of calculations : ". $data;

?>
```

You'll find everything you'll ever need to know about sessions in the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood correctly.
You can use this code at first file:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['var_name']=var_value;
```

At second file:

```
session_start();
```

Now $_SESSION['var_name'] has the value setted before.

If you want to learn more about sessions check w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp .

Comment: If unsure about the actual question it is a good habit to post a comment, not an answer...

Comment: I cant post comments cause of my reputation, but I read comments posted by other users.

Comment: Oh, I did not know there are such restrictions! All fine!

Comment: I can post comments at my posts and at all answers of my questions till I have reputation 50. See http://stackoverflow.com/privileges .

Comment: !! Please !! Never link to w3schools !! The quality of their content is horrible! See here: http://w3fools.com/